# What is the difference between 'timetamp with time zone' and 'timestamptz' in typeorm?

Tags: postgresql, nestjs, typeorm

I am currently using postgres and nestjs. What would be the difference between :

```
@Column({ type: 'timestamptz', default: () => 'CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(6)' })
recordedDateTime: Date;
```

and

```
@Column({ type: 'timestamp with time zone', default: () => 'CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(6)' })
recordedDateTime: Date;
```

Comment: `timestamptz` is an alias for `timestamp with time zone`, no difference.

Answer (score 2):

They are the same, no difference at all.
`timestamptz` is an abbreviation for `timestamp with time zone`. See [the documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/datatype-datetime.html):

> `timestamptz` is accepted as an abbreviation for `timestamp with time zone`; this is a PostgreSQL extension.

Comment: Yes, you are right in postgres .Both column will have same data if I add the data direclty using sql. However I tried saving the same object in two column using save() function using typeorm. One with column type 'timestamp with time zone' and another 'timestamptz'. Two column had different values even though the ddl of two column is the same (Created the table through nestjs migration).  I am guessing it has to do with typeorm most specifically.